# Owl carousel creates extra space at the end

Tags: css, angular, owl-carousel

Owl Carousel creates an empty space at the end of the carousel when i slide to the the last item. I am not sure whether it is default behaviour but it looks odd to me.

In this we can see the extra space I'm talking about at the end of the carousel. Here is the code I used so far :

I am using `autowidth = true` because i will be using the carousel code for different card types(different widths)...**My issue occurs only when i slide to the last item..while sliding to the last item has an empty space**

Comment: Can you add your html sathya

Comment: please create a code snippet of your code. thanks

Comment: sure..i will update

Answer (score 2):

please add the items into the options,

items : 3 (The number of items you want to see on the screen.)

```
 $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({


      autoWidth:true,
      loop:false,
      items:3,
      center:false,
      dots: false,
      merge:true,
      margin:10,
      lazyload:false,
      nav:true,
      navText: [
        '        <svg class="first" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="62" height="62" viewBox="0 0 62 62"><defs><style>.a1{fill:#fff;stroke:#ec7f4a;stroke-width:4px;}.b1{stroke:#000;}.c1{stroke:none;}.d1{fill:none;}.e1{filter:url(#a1);}</style><filter id="a1" x="0" y="0" width="62" height="62" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><feOffset dy="3" input="SourceAlpha"/><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" result="b"/><feFlood flood-opacity="0.161"/><feComposite operator="in" in2="b"/><feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/></filter></defs><g transform="translate(-1527 -173)"><g class="e1" transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 1527, 173)"><g class="a1" transform="translate(9 6)"><circle class="c1" cx="22" cy="22" r="22"/><circle class="d1" cx="22" cy="22" r="20"/></g></g><path class="b1" d="M4,11H16.17L10.58,5.41,12,4l8,8-8,8-1.41-1.41L16.17,13H4Z" transform="translate(1570 213) rotate(180)"/></g></svg>',
        '        <svg class="hide-show animate" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="62" height="62" viewBox="0 0 62 62"><defs><style>.a{fill:#fff;stroke:white;stroke-width:4px;}.b{stroke:#000;}.c{stroke:none;}.d{fill:none;}.e{filter:url(#a);}.animate .d,.a{animation: load-icon 1.5s linear .4s ;stroke-dasharray: 200;animation-direction: alternate-reverse;}@keyframes load-icon {to {stroke-dashoffset:200;stroke:#EC7F4A;}}</style><filter id="a" x="0" y="0" width="62" height="62" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><feOffset dy="3" input="SourceAlpha"/><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" result="b"/><feFlood flood-opacity="0.161"/><feComposite operator="in" in2="b"/><feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/></filter></defs><g transform="translate(-11 -173)"><g class="e" transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 11, 173)"><g class="a" transform="translate(9 6)"><circle class="c" cx="22" cy="22" r="22"/><circle class="d" cx="22" cy="22" r="20"/></g></g><path class="b" d="M20,11H7.83l5.59-5.59L12,4,4,12l8,8,1.41-1.41L7.83,13H20Z" transform="translate(54 213) rotate(-180)"/></g></svg>            '
      ]



  })
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

By adding the `items` you can control the display items. And also based on your screen width using `responsive` you control the display items.

Below example I have added like that. Hope this will work for you.

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({  
  loop:false,
  center:false,
  dots: false,
  items:4,
  merge:true,
  margin:10,
  lazyload:false,   
  margin: 10,
  nav:true,
  navText: [
  '<svg class="first" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="62" height="62" viewBox="0 0 62 62"><defs><style>.a1{fill:#fff;stroke:#ec7f4a;stroke-width:4px;}.b1{stroke:#000;}.c1{stroke:none;}.d1{fill:none;}.e1{filter:url(#a1);}</style><filter id="a1" x="0" y="0" width="62" height="62" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><feOffset dy="3" input="SourceAlpha"/><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" result="b"/><feFlood flood-opacity="0.161"/><feComposite operator="in" in2="b"/><feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/></filter></defs><g transform="translate(-1527 -173)"><g class="e1" transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 1527, 173)"><g class="a1" transform="translate(9 6)"><circle class="c1" cx="22" cy="22" r="22"/><circle class="d1" cx="22" cy="22" r="20"/></g></g><path class="b1" d="M4,11H16.17L10.58,5.41,12,4l8,8-8,8-1.41-1.41L16.17,13H4Z" transform="translate(1570 213) rotate(180)"/></g></svg>',
  '<svg class="hide-show animate" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="62" height="62" viewBox="0 0 62 62"><defs><style>.a{fill:#fff;stroke:white;stroke-width:4px;}.b{stroke:#000;}.c{stroke:none;}.d{fill:none;}.e{filter:url(#a);}.animate .d,.a{animation: load-icon 1.5s linear .4s ;stroke-dasharray: 200;animation-direction: alternate-reverse;}@keyframes load-icon {to {stroke-dashoffset:200;stroke:#EC7F4A;}}</style><filter id="a" x="0" y="0" width="62" height="62" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><feOffset dy="3" input="SourceAlpha"/><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" result="b"/><feFlood flood-opacity="0.161"/><feComposite operator="in" in2="b"/><feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/></filter></defs><g transform="translate(-11 -173)"><g class="e" transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 11, 173)"><g class="a" transform="translate(9 6)"><circle class="c" cx="22" cy="22" r="22"/><circle class="d" cx="22" cy="22" r="20"/></g></g><path class="b" d="M20,11H7.83l5.59-5.59L12,4,4,12l8,8,1.41-1.41L7.83,13H20Z" transform="translate(54 213) rotate(-180)"/></g></svg>            '
  ],
  autoplay: true,
  autoplayHoverPause: true,
  responsive: {
    0: {
    items: 2
    },
    767: {
    items: 3
    },
    1024: {
    items: 4
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-wrap">
    <div class="owl-carousel">
        <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry forgot to mention this..i am using autowidth = true because i will be using the carousel code for different card types(different widths)...My  issue occurs only when i slide to the last item..while sliding to the last item has an empty space

Comment: You have to update the full code with fiddle link and then only we come to know the main issues.

Comment: I have exactly replicated the same error in this codepen ..https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZPRajx

Comment: Yes sathya. You have to use `responsive` to control items and extend the item width without space.

Comment: When you slide to the end of the carousel you will see some empty space.. thanks for the help !

Comment: As per my sample

Comment: Responsive option doesnt seem to work for me... codepen.io/anon/pen/ZPRajx